# How to improve slow redirects between pages in production of NextJS websites with custom server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have deployed my nextjs app in shared hosting in AWS EC2 with command

pm2 start npm --name "app_name" -- start

But the **production build is very slow**. Redirection between the pages are very slow, like if I click on any button it takes forever to go to that page.

I am using custom server since I need to run the app in https which is not possible without custom server (as far as I know, feel free to guide on this).

My custom server.js look like:

```
// const { createServer } = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const https = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const fs = require("fs");

const dev = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRO !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRO, "env variable");

let pKeyPath = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/appsinvo.co.uk/privkey.pem";
let cPath = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/appsinvo.co.uk/fullchain.pem";

const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(pKeyPath),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(cPath),
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
  https
    .createServer(httpsOptions, async (req, res) => {
      await handle(req, res);
    })
    .listen(7000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on https://localhost:443");
    });

  http
    .createServer((req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(301, {
        Location: `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`,
      });
      res.end();
  })
    .listen(7000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:8080");
    });
});
```

My package.json file is as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "analyze:server": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=server next build",
    "analyze:browser": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=browser next build"
},
```

The first render of the site is very slow. Below is what I am getting in the network tab.

[image]

If I check the first thing in the network tab which is basically the root path ("/") of the website, it shows the below error:

[image]

Also the Javascript is loading before everything else like the main.ts, _app.ts which are heavy JS.

The first load of the app is also very high among the pages.

[image]

I googled and came across various articles and did all the package removal of unused dependencies and dynamic import of the component where necessary but still the first load of the components are very high. I also removed the prefect={false} from the Link imported from next/link.

So my questions are:

1. How to make the first load of the page faster ?
2. How to config the custom server for the production build ?
3. How to reduce the first load js of all the components ?

Kindly help as I have been doing this for a week now and I am nowhere near a good user experience.

Comment: probably you can ask yourself the question what's different between server and your local, not nextJS part, but any other async process, ex. API, hard disk, whatever.